# reading input into array without hard coding

Tags: java, android, arrays, user-input

So I was thinking that maybe other people might have had this problem. I'm a total beginner .I am using java to program for android so I can test on my phone. When I read in inputs from my array,

example:

```
int[] myArray = new int[5];
```

I tend to hard code the inputs into the array.

```
int input1= nextInt("input1");
int input2= nextInt("input2");
```

etc..

```
myArray[1]= input1;
myArray[2]= input2;
```

etc..

but this is time consuming, especially if the bounds of the array are higher.

ie.
 `int[] myArray = new int[50]`;

So my question is, how is this all done the shortest way possible? without the timely hard coding.

Comment: Where are these values coming from?

Comment: they would come from here.

public void createUI() {
  
  createInput("input1");
                createInput("input2");
  setButtonLabel("Submit");


 }

Comment: That makes even less sense to me than the original code snippets.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my suggestion if you know the input length:

```
int[] arr = new int[50];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = nextInt("input" + i);
```

Else I would suggest using a `while`-loop and an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a `for` loop or `while` loop to save time and for repetitive actions.

e.g,

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < myArray.length; counter++)
{
   myArray[counter] = counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

```
for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    myArray[i] = nextInt("input" + (i + 1));; // or whatever...
}
```